# Concluding a polynomial is linear through limits

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

> $p$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and for every natural $n$ we have $p(n)>n$. $x_k $ is a sequence that: $x_1=1, x_{i+1}=p(x_i)$ for every $N$ one of $x_i$ is divisible by $N.$ Prove that $p(x)=x+1$

---

I proved that the sequence $d_n = x_{n+1}-x_n$ is increasing and bounded hence eventually constant. Now I considered the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$, from the $\infty / \infty$ case of Stolz Cesaro lemma, and using the fact $x_{n+1}-x_n$ is eventually constant, we can say the above limit is equal to $1$. But, letting $p(x)=a_kx^k+...+a_0$, writing the same limit out, we get $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}= \frac{a_k (x_n)^k+...+a_0}{x_n}= a_k (x_n)^{k-1}+a_{k-1} (x_n)^{k-2}+...+\frac{a_0}{x_n}$$ Now the limit clearly goes to infinity, the only way the limit is finite is when the coefficients $a_k=a_{k-1}=...=0$ thus it becomes a linear polynomial.
**My question** is whether my conclusion on it being linear polynomial through this method is correct or not, that is concluding the coefficients are $0$. Please tell.

Comment: It is not clear to me how Stolz Cesaro is applied here.

Comment: Using Thm 1. (https://brilliant.org/wiki/stolzcesaro-theorem/) $x_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence, then as $x_{n+1}-x_n$ is eventually constant so $\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \lim \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_n -x_{n-1}}=1$

Answer (score 0):

What you did almost works, the only little error is that you cannot make a conclusion about $a_0$ from your last limit (which should be obvious once you realize that you need to prove $a_0=1$ a bit later).

But I think you overengineered the part you showed in the proof. It's possible to get at the conclusion using only that $x_{n+1} - x_{n}$ is bounded from above (which is totally unclear to me how to prove that and seems to be the core of the problem).

Using that, and using $x_{n+1} > x_{n}$ (from $p(k) > k$) we now have a polyonomial $p(x)$, a bound $M$ and sequence $(x_n)$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n= \infty$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb N: 0 < x_{n+1} - x_{n} \le M$.

OTOH, using $p(x)=a_kx^k+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$ we know that $a_k > 0$ and get
$$x_{n+1} - x_{n} = p(x_n) - x_n = a_kx_n^k+\ldots+(a_1-1)x_n+a_0$$
This can only be bounded from above if $k \le 1$ and then can only be bounded from below if $k=1$, then $a_1=1$ follows from being bounded in both directions.

That means you only have to consider with $p(x) = x+a_0$, and concluding $a_0=1$ is easy using $N=a_0$.